# How to program STM32L011

Tags: stm32, low-power

I tried to program specific STM ultra-low power series (STM32L011D4-tssop14).
JLink programmer doesn't support this type of STM32 MCUs.
so I tried to program this MCU by STLINK-V2 (SW mode). to do this I am doing the following works:

1- connect all wire which needed for this task (GND-VCC-SWDIO-SWCLK)

2- select "option for target..." in Keil
3- going to debug tab and select "ST-link debugger"

4- going to setting => as I know in "SW Device" section I should see the device information but I have an error " NO target Connected ".

that's weird for me when I connect RST pin of MCU to ground "SW Device" section showed device information.
in this way, if I push F8 (Load in Keil) error appears "Core is held in reset"

it's reasonable when I force MCU to reset ( connect RST pin to GND) the program process shouldn't work ( "Core is held in reset" ) but if I don't do that programmer cant connect to the micro ("NO target Connected")

I don't know how should I Program this MCU...

Comment: You'll likely need to either use programmer software which can do a coordinated manipulation of the reset line, or else do something to prevent the MCU from running code which disables SWD or sleeps; for example, you could use the boot mode pins to make it start up to the ROM bootloader.   This is probably a duplicate of one or more previous questions on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JLink programmer doesn't support this type of STM32 MCUs.

The [SEGGER website](https://www.segger.com/downloads/supported-devices.php) lists the STM32L011D4 as a supported MCU. Check your jlink software version.

You may need the "connect under Reset" option - don't know where that is in Keil settings. This obviously requires the reset line to be connected to the debugger.